# ZODB python database with Filestorage: why do temporary files stay on the disk?

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, python-3.6, zodb

I'm experimenting with the ZODB database module in Python 3.6. In my experiment, I create a `TreeSet()` and fill it with data. Then I commit the transaction (which saves the changes to disk) and close the database.

```
from ZODB.FileStorage import FileStorage
from ZODB import DB
from persistent import Persistent
from BTrees.OOBTree import TreeSet
import transaction

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # 1. Create ZODB database
    # ------------------------
    storage = FileStorage("C:/database_test/mydb.db")
    db = DB(storage)
    conn = db.open()
    root = conn.root()
    root.files = TreeSet()


    # 2. Fill the TreeSet
    # --------------------
    ...

    # 3. Save and close
    # ------------------
    transaction.commit()
    conn.close()
    db.close() # <- is this even necessary?
```

I look at the files remaining on my harddrive. As you can see, there are three temporary files remaining there - even after I've closed the database.

[image]

Did I close something (*database*, *connection*, *storage*, *transaction*, ...) not properly?

---

**Note:**
I don't know if this is important, but my system is as follows:

- Windows 10, 64-bit
- Python 3.6.3
- ZODB 5.4.0 (is latest version as of now - 18 May 2018)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.index` file is not a temporary file, but it is the index file that is persisted.  If absent, it will always be fully regenerated (which will take a bit of time for a larger database).

The `.temp` file is for transient data that is generated before being fully committed.

The `.lock` file is to ensure that no two process open that file.  It contains the PID of the last process that opened it.  If it has terminated a new process will then write its PID into it.

There are actually more files than this, and they are documented inside the [class docstring](https://github.com/zopefoundation/ZODB/blob/5.4.0/src/ZODB/FileStorage/FileStorage.py#L187).

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not really temporary files. They are permanent files with sometimes transient data.

> In addition to the data file, some ancillary files are created. These can be lost without affecting data integrity, however losing the index file may cause extremely slow startup. (http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/reference/storages.html#included-storages)